# Changing images periodically in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

So basically I want to change image in every 5 second, so I wrote the following Javascript code and tag it to html. But the console keep saying that "No javaScript on this page" and the code does not apply

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>JavaScript for Programmers</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Mood Change</h2>
        <p>The mood of this web page changes every 5 seconds.</p>
        <p><img id="mood" src="frown.gif" alt="mood"></p>
        <script async src="../scripts/moody.js"></scripts>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
  var images=[]
  images[0]="smile.gif";
  images[1]="frown.gif";
  var myMood= document.getElementById("mood");
  function change(){
    if(myMood==images[0]){
      myMood.src=images[1];
    }
    else if(myMood.src==imgaes[1]){
      myMood.src=images[0];
    }
 }

 setInterval(change,5000);
```

Comment: You have a syntax error, try adding a ";" after images=[] so it becomes "var images=[];"

Comment: @pixelchild—that isn't a syntax error, it's just a missing semi-colon that is automatically inserted per the rules in [*ECMA-262*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.9).

Answer (score 2):

`</scripts>` should be `</script>`

Also your JS could look like this: http://jsbin.com/nawono/2/edit

```
var myMood= document.getElementById("mood");
var images=[
    "smile.gif",
    "frown.gif"
];

function change(){
    myMood.src= images.reverse()[0];
}

setInterval(change,5000);
```

Ahh, to explain `images.reverse()[0];`, it reverses the array order and we always take out the `0` indexed key. Quite nice

Comment: Thanks! I tried your code and it works.But why didn't my version work? I'm still learning JS, and I haven't learn reverse() method

Comment: @HanHai you're welcome. See this line of yours `if(myMood==images[0]){`? Well, `myMood` is an document Element, not an Array, so `==` will always return `false`. `</scripts>` is not a valid HTML tag, your JS is way too complicated for such a simple task. Read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse and good luck with coding!

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code didn't work is you comparison is in appropriate. Where you have:

```
var images=[]
  images[0]="smile.gif";
  images[1]="frown.gif";
  var myMood= document.getElementById("mood");

  function change(){
    if (myMood == images[0]) {
```

then *myMood* is a DOM element and *images[0]* is a string. Those two will never almost never be equal (unless the DOM element's *toString* methods produces exactly the same string).

You probably meant:

```
    if (myMood.src == images[0]) {
```

so that you compare two strings that are more likely to be the same.

Comment: Thank you RobG. I fix this error, but the image still doesn't change as I want it to